# How to store each output line of fgets() into separate variable?

Tags: php

fgets() shows output is as below =

string(10) "1236457" string(8) "xyz" string(15) "credit:87845 " string(17) "balance:644546 " string(17) "remaining:7463847"

i want to store $var1=1236457 $var2= xyz and same for all.But without using explode.

Comment: `explode` does exactly what you don't want it to and what it implies, it "explodes" a string in to an array, you could look in to `list`.

Comment: Isn't that a bit hard to use? Don't you think an array is easier than say 100 variables named $line52, $line53 etc?

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on having variables you can iterate the array and create associative keys and then use extract to create the variables.
In this example I use 0 indexed lines, meaning first line is $line0.

```
$arr = explode("\n", $str);
Foreach($arr as $key => $val){
   $new["line" . $key] = $val;
}

Extract($new);

Echo $line2;
```

https://3v4l.org/psh6H

Comment: thanks it works fine.But is any php function available to separate this line .without using explode.Sorry  if this is silly question.

Comment: There is other ways, but I believe explode is the fastest.

Comment: @K.Nagare - Why does it matter if you use `explode()` or some other function that does the same thing?